# Jquery not handle HTTP errors when the request gets failed

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, hybrid-mobile-app

My problem is "simple". I'm developing a hybrid Android application that makes HTTP requests via Jquery Ajax.
The problem is that when my requests gets failed(Server returns 401/403 ...etc), Jquery fires only HTTP 404 error that is not correct.

I'm making HTTP post requests like that:

```
    var request = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: obj,
    cache: false,
    contentType : 'application/json',
    beforeSend : function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password));
    },  
    success: function(data){
        // Success
    },
    error: function(request, status, errorThrown){

        console.log("call Login ajax failed with error, status:" + status + " errorThrown:" + errorThrown);
        console.log("call Login ajax failed with errorCode : " + request.status);

    }
```

The strange thing is that when i run my project as DynamicWeb project in my browser at my PC and in the url use my ip address the jquery fires the correct error events, but when i use "localhost" in the url, the jquery act as in the android devices, fires only 404 event.
I tried to change jquery libary to a newest version 2.1.1 but this doesn't help.
PS. I'm using jquery 2.0.2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem for me was that server doesn't allow Cross-domain requests. So i must set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:", "*" header in responses from my server and everything will be ok...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the header of the response to Content-type: application/json.

Before you echo the json. Or you could set the type of the ajax call to text, html.

Also it is recommended to chain your callback functions with jquery like so

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  headers: { "Accept-Encoding" : "gzip" }, // Use the response seen in sniffer
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',//be sure you are receiving a valid json response or you'll get an error
})
.done(function(response) {
  console.log("success");
  console.log(response);
})
.fail(function() {
  console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
  console.log("complete");
});
```

Comment: I saw that Android device fires this in logCat:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load url. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
I think there is a problem with Cross-Domain requests. I check that the client set Origin:null header no-matter if i set Origin tag in the Ajax.
The main hit is to set Allow-Origin Header in Jboss at container level.
I've created a filter but its execute only on application level, the goal is to create filter on jboss level and to set Allow-Origin header at all responses...

Comment: The main hit is to make Jboss set Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*"  in the HTTP response's headers...

Comment: I'm using jboss filter to catch the client's request and set the header, but my filter can't catch the requests on jboss container level, only on application level...

Comment: change dataType: 'json' to dataType: 'jsonp'